# Different definitions of the $E^{\infty}$ page of a spectral sequence.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, spectral-sequences

In *Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology by Davis and Kirk* it seems that given a (convergent, bigraded) spectral sequence $(E^r, d^r)$ one defines the $E^{\infty}$-page as $$E^r_{p, q} = \operatorname{colim}_{r \to \infty}E^r_{p, q}.$$

However it seems that the convention (at least by books such as *Weibel's: An Introduction to Homological Algebra* and *Rotman's An Introduction to Homological Algebra*) is that for *any* (bigraded) spectral sequence $(E^r, d^r)$, one defines $E^{\infty}_{p, q}$ in the following way. Suppose that $d^r$ has bidegree $(a, b)$, then we define $B^r_{p, q} = \operatorname{im} d^r_{p-a, q-b} : E^r_{p-a, q-b} \to E^r_{p, q}$ and $Z^r_{p, q} = \operatorname{ker} d^r_{p, q} : E^r_{p, q} \to E^r_{p+a, q+b}$ so that $$E^{r+1}_{p, q} = Z^r_{p, q} / B^r_{p, q}.$$

Then one defines $$E^{\infty}_{p, q} = \frac{\bigcap_r Z^r_{p, q}}{\bigcup_r B^r_{p, q}}.$$

Now at some point in *Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology by Davis and Kirk* it seems that implicitly it is the case that $$E^{\infty}_{p, q} = \bigcap_{r}E^r_{p, q}$$ as in one of the proofs it is stated that $E^{\infty}_{n, 0} = \bigcap_r E^r_{n, 0}$, which leads me to guess that the above holds.

More confusingly still, it seems that in an earlier version of *Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology by Davis and Kirk*, the $E^{\infty}$-page was defined as $$E^{\infty}_{p, q} = \lim_{r \to \infty} E^r_{p, q}$$ as indicated by this question here on Math.StackExchange: [definition of convergence of a spectral sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439264/definition-of-convergence-of-a-spectral-sequence)

---

So it seems that there are *possibly* four ways of defining the $E^{\infty}$ page of spectral sequence, in what ways are these equivalent? Do they agree for convergent spectral sequences?

Also I don't see how the authors could swap out taking a colimit for a direct limit as categorically speaking those should be dual notions.

Also I'd like to mention that I am inferring a lot from the text, I'm sure that it is due to a misinterpretation on my part, (and not the authors) that I've claimed something incorrect to hold.

Comment: Well, here comes a lot of notation into play, the thing with the intersections and the quotient for sure is the same if it collapses at siome point, and I presume as well generally, although I would be a little careful there. 
the infinite intersection is by definition just the colimit, and the ptoblem with the limit in the end is that the idea of a directed limit is older, and a direct limit is actually a colimit (if I remember correctly) and so i think there is just notation of people clashing.

Comment: Have you read McCleary's book, *A User's Guide To Spectral Sequences*? Specifically $\S$ 1.2.2, which compares the way spectral sequences arise from filtered differential modules and from exact couples.

Comment: @Tyrone I have read that section specifically, but I have a copy of the book and will take a look at it.

Comment: @Tyrone Sorry, I meant to say that I _haven't_ read that section specifically, but I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Enkidu Is the colimit by definition just the infinite intersection? I guess it may be notation clashing as you said, but I've been told by someone else that the colimit was the infinite union and the limit was the infinite intersection. Could you provide me with a reference to read further and to verify that the colimit is actually by  definition just the infinite intersection?

Comment: @Perturbative exactly that is the problem, some people use the $\lim$ notation for the direct limit, which actually is a colimit so that might explain the clash of lim and colim. The precise structure of the colimit however depends on the maps,  which means that big quotient might still work out.
Also you always need to remember in which world all the papers work, since sometimes intersections don't make sense. For example $\cap E^R_{p,q}$ actually does not make sense on its own (as the spaces are actually not subsets of each other) .
So you really need to be careful there

Comment: the nlab is always a good start for stuff like that, since they tend to be very very precise. Respectively good old Weibel!